# Insufficient privileges exception while creating Azure Ad policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Got below exception while trying to create new policy under Azure ad.

[image]

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @("{`"TokenLifetimePolicy`":{`"Version`":1,`"MaxAgeSingleFactor`":`"2.00:00:00`"}}") -DisplayName "TestPolicy" -IsOrganizationDefault 1 -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

What are all the prerequisites to create policy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what policy are you creating? what is your requirement. Kindly elaborate

Comment: I am creating policy to **extend token life time to the maximum** value. My requirement is to generate access token for my Azure AD. By default access token expiration will be 1 hour. To update the maximum value for expiration i need to create policy like this. Referred link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes]

Comment: Compare the New-AzureADPolicy command and your screenshot , seems the command is not the one you get error  . Please confirm which command  you are using ?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Updated proper screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried to use your Azure AD admin account to perform the operation .